# Hadoop mapper/reducer re-use

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

How do mapper/reducer instances get re-used within a jvm that's kept alive perpetually?

For example, let's say I wanted to do something like this:

```
public class MyMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<K1, V1, K2, V2> {

    private Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

    public void map(K1 k1, V1 v1, OutputCollector<K2, V2> output, Reporter reporter) {
        ... do stuff ...

        set.add(k1.toString()); //add something to a list so that it can be used later

        ... do other stuff ...


        if(set.contains("someString"))
            emitSomeKindOfOutput(output);
        else
            emitSomeOtherKindOfOutput(output);
    }

}
```

If the same mapper can be used for multiple tasks/jobs, then the member set could cause problems because it would still contain other junk from previous tasks/jobs. Is this kind of re-use possible in hadoop? What about for reducers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are definitely safe. Mapper and reducer instance are not reused. If you need to perform some initialization or cleanup you can override the two methods `configure` and `close` provided by MapReduceBase. This is not required by your code sample.

If `set` was a static variable then you would have to `clear` it in the `close()` method to be safe, even if not required by most site configuration (basically a new JVM is forked for each map by default, you have to configure `reuse.jvm.num.tasks` to enable JVM reuse). Two map tasks are never run concurrently in the same JVM.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Hadoop is based on a shared nothing architecture and so your 'private Set set' variable won't get shared among different mappers. So, there shouldn't be any question of getting, as you mentioned - 'junk from previous mappers'.

Comment: Will a particular mapper instance be re-used for more than one task/job?

Comment: @Seth no it will not (as per default). Every time a new mapper/reducer instance will be created - in a new JVM.